# Rake Assets:precompile failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundle, precompile

New to rails, and I can't figure or find where exactly is the problem.

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class
get@(execjs):3538:630
(execjs):4058:47
(execjs):1:46
global code@(execjs):1:58
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in`'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Here is the complete with --trace:

voke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in`sprockets_context'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in`asset_url'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:209:in `font_url'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:143:in`_perform'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in`visit_prop'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`block in visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`with_frame'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:504:in `block (2 levels) in visit_directive'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:504:in`map'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:504:in `block in visit_directive'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in`with_environment'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:503:in `visit_directive'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`block in with_base'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`with_base'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in`block in visit_children'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in`visit_children'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in`with_environment'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`block in visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in`visit'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in`render'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in`call'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in`call_processor'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in`reverse_each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in`load_from_unloaded'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in`fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in`block in initialize'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in`find_asset'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in`block in find'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in`block in stat_tree'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in`each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in`stat_tree'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in`block in logical_paths'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in`logical_paths'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in`compile'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in`with_logger'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in`block in execute'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in`execute'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in`mon_synchronize'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in`invoke'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in`block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in`block in top_level'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in`top_level'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/rake:22:in`'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in`kernel_load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in`exec'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in`dispatch'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in`start'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in`with_friendly_errors'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in`load'
/Users/al/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

Comment: Are you using ES6 in you js files?

Comment: Also, try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace` for more in depth information about the error.